# Ethereum Smart Contract deploys fine on Kovan, fails on Main Net. Gas too low or what?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm deploying a smart contract using its bytecode in wallet.ethereum.org. I deployed it on Kovan and Rinkeby networks and it went very smooth and fast, fee was 1782250 gas @ 4 Gwei price.

With the exact same bytecode, I tried deploying on Main Net with higher gas than recommended by wallet.ethereum.org, my last try was with a limit of 5,882,250 Gas @ 6 Gwei price.

But still, processing takes a long long time and ultimately fails without an error message.

The transaction ID generated returns non-existent.(https://etherscan.io/tx/0x28e8547958c9f72d91128a12fd8c32082d290244383b16a05fb49078b58dc142)

Also tried using Remix with the contract code itself (not bytecode) and same thing happens, deploys ok on Test Networks, fails on Main Net. The contract is a standard BurnableToken from OpenZeppelin.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: did the tx drop? there is no fail message it says that tx number doesn't exist

Comment: Etherscan will say it can’t find the transaction if it hasn’t seen it on the network for awhile. This will happen if you set the gas price too low. I’ve had cases where transactions disappear for a few days then suddenly appear (but still don’t get processed and have very long estimated completion times). However, this happens with really low gas prices (this was 1 Gwen for me). Have you ever seen the transaction show up on Etherscan? Did you look for it on another provider like Infura? Are you sure you set the gas price correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with Metamask. Tried it with myEtherWallet and it worked.